# Regex for form field validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form which has a field of a special type.this needs validation.
Conditions

1. It must contain at least 1 letter.upper case and  lower case both are allowed [mandatory]
2. It can contain a number [optional]
3. It can contain any 1 or all 3  of the following special characters    hyphen (-), ampersand (&), period (.)[optional]
4. Length minimum of 5 maximum of 100
5. Can contain space between letters [optional]

I tried this pattern

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[\s]+|[\.]+|[\&]+|[\-]+/
```

But it doesn't give the expected output.

examples:

```
abcd xyz ->must pass test(letter must, 5<characters count<100,space optional)
abcdxyz  ->must pass test(letter must, 5<characters count<100,space optional)
abcd & ->must pass test
abcd1234 ->must pass test
abcd.xyz.12 ->must pass test
123456 ->must fail test(no letters found)
&&&&&&& ->must fail test(no letters found)
&&&--..& ->must fail test(no letters found)
123 abcd.xyz 777-& !$ ->must fail test(!$ are not allowed)
```

I can count the string length separately,but i need the regex for the rest part.
I am using

```
str.match(/regex/)
```

Comment: Is this a password field?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also share your efforts you have made. Also your write up is a bit ambiguous and not very clear. It may help if you clearly state your rules.

Comment: Please give examples of data that fail your validation.  This should include examples  that should fail but instead pass,  and examples that should pass but instead fail.

Comment: explaining how regular expressions work in the detail you require is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.   Assuming that your 5 conditions can be satisfied in any order, you will need to understand "lookahead".  See more on that topic here:  https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Another thing that can be asked too is: do you really need this validation to be done by a regex? couldn't you check these conditions separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can test length separately, this could do the job: `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 .&-]*)?[a-zA-Z]+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 .&-]*)?$`. What makes it hard to count here is that `{5,100}` would test the number of occurences of a subpattern and not the total of letters it found.

explanation (in order):

- start of string
- can optionally find any number of letter/number and " .&-"
- must found at least one letter
- can optionally find any number of letter/number and " .&-"
- end of string

example adapted from [Regex101 code generator](https://regex101.com/r/WqkEOW/1):

```js
const regex = /^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 .&-]*)?[a-zA-Z]+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 .&-]*)?$/;
const strs = [
    'abcd xyz',
    'abcdxyz',
    'abcd &',
    'abcd1234',
    'abcd.xyz.12',
    '123456',
    '&&&&&&&',
    '&&&--..&',
    '123 abcd.xyz 777-& !$'
];
let m, i, l = strs.length;

for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
    if( (m = strs[i].match(regex)) ){
        console.log('Found match: ', m);
    }else{
        console.log('Doesn\'t match: ', strs[i]);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: If you meant to use this for a password, [rules like this are a bad idea](https://xkcd.com/936/) and now officially discouraged